# Core Text Background Color for iOS 6

Tags: ios6, background-color, core-text, nsattributedstring

I am using NSAttributedString in iOS6 and I cannot seem to get this to work:

```
[attributedString addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName
                           value:[UIColor yellowColor]
                           range:range];
```

Is this method call and `NSBackgroundColorAttributeName` supported in iOS6?

**Edit:**
Solved it. It was a legacy issue on my side. The previous kct* (eg. `kctforegroundcolorattributename`) string attribute constants were still being used. These prevented the newer API values from being implemented correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You must use an [NSMutableAttributedString](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableAttributedString/addAttribute%3avalue%3arange%3a)